# Bootstrap 3 Active state causes error on Navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigationbar

I'm creating a static navigation bar with a JQuery active state border bottom when I select one of the navigation options.

However, I think Bootstrap 3 is causing a weird issue with the active state, because whenever I click on one of the links the spacing of the Navigation links gets smaller and the li shift to the top.

**Is there a way to prevent Bootstrap 3 active state from shifting my Navigation links?**

**UPDATE** I figured out that the problem was the JQUERY active selector I'm still troubleshooting it: https://jsfiddle.net/88z02dx6/

```
$('.vnavbar ul li a').click(function() {
    $('active').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active a');
});
```

**BONUS:** For some reason I can't get the dropdown menu to work either I don't want it to highlight on hover or on active state, I just want it to bring down a dropdown list when I click on it. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23151/

**CSS:**

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.bodyh {height:100%; background-color:blue;}

.tabs {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table; /* [1] */
    table-layout: fixed; /* [2] */
    width: 100%; /* [3] */
}

    .tabs__item {
        display: table-cell; /* [4] */
    }

        .tabs__link {
            display: block; /* [5] */
        }


/**
 * Primary nav. Extends `.tabs`.
 *
 * 1. Stop tabs’ corners leaking out beyond our 4px round.
 */
.primary-nav {
    text-align: center;  height:48px; position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; background:#333 !important; border-radius: 0 !important; /* [1] */
}

        .primary-nav a {
            padding: 1em;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .primary-nav a:hover {
            background-color: #666;
        }

.primary-nav a.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f90;  color: #f90;   padding:1em; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Content</a>
    </li>

    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Voozlr</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Store</a>
    </li>

      <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Mail</a>
    </li>



              <li class="dropdown tabs__item">


            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle tabs__link" dropdown-toggle="" data-toggle="dropdown">Me <b class="caret"></b>   
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

</ul>

          </nav>            
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->    
    </header>
  <div class="bodyh"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A.** see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23155/)**

1. if you add a `border` to `a.active` you must make sure the space for that `border` is already there, or you will have some visual problems. so use :

   ```
   border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
   ```
2. you have a class `tabs__link` on `a` before you click. to that class you have a css style of `display:block`. by removing all the classes that `a` has, you loose that style. so you need to add `display:block` to `a` also.

so in the end you have this code

```
 .primary-nav a {
        padding: 1em;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        display:block;
        border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
    }
```

**B.** **OR** another way to do this ( here i include also solution for dropdown menu )

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23156/)**

1. to also keep class `dropdown-toggle` on `a` that is inside the `li.dropdown` , and also keep the `tabs__link` class, you should use this ( so you don't need to add `display:block` on `a` like in the previous solution )

   ```
   $('li:not(.dropdown) a').attr('class', 'tabs__link');
   $('li.dropdown a').attr('class', 'dropdown-toggle tabs__link');
   ```
2. for the `.dropdown-menu` to work you first need to delete the `overflow:hidden` from `.primary-nav` . then you need a little JQ to `slideToggle()` the `.dropdown-menu` when you click on an `a.dropdown-toggle`

   ```
   if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle')){
       $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle()
   }else{
       $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp()
   }
   ```

so. in the end you have a JQ like this

```
$('.vnavbar ul li a').click(function() {
    $('li:not(.dropdown) a').attr('class', 'tabs__link');
    $('li.dropdown a').attr('class', 'dropdown-toggle tabs__link');

    $(this).addClass('active');

    if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle')){
        $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle()
    }else{
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp()
    }

});
```

Comment: I never knew about the: Border-bottom:4px solid transparent; solution,  and I completely overlooked using display: block on a, that's my fault, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Any other advice on how to get the dropdown list to work, I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the in-depth explanation. Have a great day!